# Prove that the derivative of $e^x-e^{-x} \geq 2$

Tags: calculus

Given
$$f(x)=e^x-e^{-x}$$
prove that
$$f'(x)\geq 2$$
I saw this question online and I don't know how to solve it.
So I found the derivative and I know that $f'(x)=f'(-x)$ but I don't know what to do after that :(

Comment: Hint : Substitute $u=e^x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, $f'(x)=f'(-x)$, but what matters here is that $f''(x)=f(x)$ and that$$f(x)\begin{cases}>0&\text{ if }x>0\\0&\text{ if }x=0\\<0&\text{ if }x<0.\end{cases}$$So, $f'$ is strictly increasing on $[0,\infty)$ and strictly decreasing on $(-\infty,0]$. Therefore, it attains its minimum at $0$. And $f'(0)=2$.

Answer (score 2):

$t+\frac  1t \geq 2$ for any positive number $t$ because $(1-t)^{2} \geq 0$. [This is also  a special case of AM-GM inequality]. Put $t=e^{x}$ to  see that $f'(x)=e^{x}+\frac  1{e^{x}} \geq 2$.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly $f'(x) =e^x +e^{-x} $
Now applying AM-GM inequality we get
$\frac {e^x +e^{-x}} 2 \geq \sqrt {e^x e^{-x}}=1  
\implies f'(x) =e^x +e^{-x}\geq 2$